# Command line argument question--Skipping optional function parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in the middle of learning command line arguments. What I want to do is print out my script that says "Hello, World" and on the CLI, if you type down

```
node helloworld (name)
```

it will print out `Hello, (name)` instead. And if no name input, it will output `Hello, World` by default.

I basically did that but I was wondering, is there any way I can just type

```
node helloworld (yourname)
```

INSTEAD of going through the hassle of typing

```
node helloworld name (yourname)
```

```js
function getArgument(argument){
  var index = process.argv.indexOf(argument);
  return (index === -1) ? null : process.argv[index+1];
}

var name = getArgument('name');
var message = name ? "Hello, " + name : "Hello, world.";
console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
```

Image link on the bottom to show you what I'm talking about. Just want to type helloworld (actualname) instead of helloworld name (actualname):

[image: CLICK FOR PICTURE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just always take the first argument:

```
 let name = process.argv[2];
```

In your case `argv` looks like this:

```
 ["node", "helloworld", "(name)"]
```

therefore you can just access the third one to get the name.

Comment: It should be `[2]` because the first two elements are `node` and `helloworld`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It boggled my mind for an hour or so